# Are the Harry Potter movies canon?

Tags: harry-potter, canon

We know there are differences between the books and the movies (the Battle of Hogwarts, etc.). Which version is considered canon? Also, if the books are canon in cases of contradiction, are things that don't contradict the books, but do include details that are not in the book, such as hermione being white in the movies, canon?

Comment: Ms Rowling really doesn't bother too much with such things. Her books are all about imagination and less about telling people what to think. In fact, book 5 is even devoted to her not liking people that expect other people to follow strict rules all that much. But I know that she has stated that the way the actors looked in the movie is not how she imagined them herself

Comment: In short, canon is whatever you want it to be. You can have your own interpretation of it.

Comment: @Simpleton Not if there are explicit canon rules set out by WoG.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Has JKR set out any such rules? In any case JKR explicitly stated that cursed child was Canon. That was hard to digest

Comment: @Simpleton No idea but your comment read as if it was talking about the general case so I replied as such.

Comment: "[Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_(fiction))" is by definition the content that is **officially recognized** by show runners or authors.  If JKR doesn't care enough to define the canon of Harry Potter then *there is no canon for Harry Potter.*  You're still free to believe whatever you like personally, of course, but "canon" means more than just "your opinion."

Comment: Each Harry Potter movies is canon with itself.  And depending on how consistent the movies are with each other and how easy it is to fit them together, some might say that all of the movies are canonical with all the other movies, and maybe some wouldn't say that.  As for the movies and the books, the movies show what the books describe, and the movies condense a lot of plot.  And some might says what the movies show fits the books' descriptions, and many omitted plot events might have happened in the movies without being seen.  continued.

Comment: continued.  And I suspect that enough plot details are different, and perhaps enough visual designs, to make the movies seem non canonical with the books.  Thus a fan might imagine that the movies and the books are both canon, but happen in alternate universes and that the book Harry Potter and the movie Harry Potter could meet if one made spells to travel to alternate universes - to kill Voldemort in all alternate universes for example.